# Is UIDevice-Reachability approved by Apple?

Tags: iphone, reachability

I have come acros this and am trying to establish if used in a project submitted to Apple for the App Store are they liable to reject it?

https://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension/blob/master/UIDevice-Reachability.h

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Applications liable to rejection code-wise are only those that use undocumented API. UIDevice reachability is not one of them. We have a few apps submitted to the app store using this functionality.